# Field values for nested structs not getting set in protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using google protobuffer for data deserialization, but my issue is that the field values for the nested structures are not getting set. I checked the bin file in a hex editor and the values look fine. However, since the first field in my nested struct is a float and if I try to get the corresponding number of bytes and decode it into a float, the value seems fine.

Can someone advice what else I can do to check this or what perhaps is happening? I have tried using ParseFromIstream as well.

the proto file is :

```
   syntax = "proto3";
   package generatedata;

   message DataSample {
   DataSample_Safe DataSafe = 1;
   uint32 PassReSts = 2;
   uint32 Dir = 3;    
   }


   message DataSample_Safe {
      float ALast = 1;
      uint32 ALastQf = 2;   
    } 

    message DataSampleMultiple
    {
       repeated DataSample finaldata = 1;
    }
```

The C++ code is

```
fstream in("test.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);

generatedata::DataSample test_data;   


while(in.read((char *) &test_data,sizeof(test_data)))
{
    const generatedata::DataSample_Safe& veh = test_data.datasafe();
    cout << "safe" << veh.alast() << endl;

    cout << "First " << test_data.passrests() << endl;
    cout << "Second " << test_data.dir() << endl;

}
```

Using ParseFromIstream, the code is

```
generatedata::DataSampleMultiple test_data;
test_data.ParseFromIstream(&in);

for(int i = 0 ; i < test_data.finaldata_size(); i ++)
{
     const generatedata::DataSample& veh = test_data.finaldata(i);
     const generatedata::DataSample_Safe& check = veh.datasafe();
     cout << "safe" <<  check.alast() << endl;

     cout << "First " << veh.passrests() << endl;
     cout << "Second " << veh.dir() << endl;
}
```

in the above case using ParseFromIstream, the final data size is 0

The first cout gives segmentation fault as the value of safe has not been set. However, the second and third couts are output correctly when using istream::read

Comment: You need to read the protocol buffer documentation.  You would not use istream::read like that, but instead something like the ParseFromIstream  method on generated message.

Comment: @DaveS : I had tried with ParseFromIstream as well but in that case all my fields have value 0 set.

Comment: How did you create the bin file?  Again, it should be something like SerializeToOstream, or the such, and not ostream::write.

Comment: The bin file has been generated by capturing data via hardware that dumps bin files and a C++ struct to explain the format of the data in the bin file

Comment: Ok, I would only reasonably expect protocol buffers to work with data written to and read from using the methods provided by the generated protocol buffer message.  Again, this is better explained in the documentation.  Otherwise you risk various flavors of undefined behavior.   See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: If you have created the file manually, may I suggest using https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to check that the contents are what you think they are?

Comment: sure. I can do that